# Выборка sql без повторений

Tags: mysql, group-by

Добрый день!

Есть такая таблица

```
id  date        date_over   time        user_id    client_id
1   2017-11-22  2017-11-24  16:07:00    1          1        
2   2017-11-22  2017-11-23  16:10:00    1          2    
3   2017-11-24  2017-11-25  12:10:00    1          1
```

Помогите составить запрос чтобы убрать дубли по client_id, и самое сложное здесь для меня это убрать старые записи то есть сделать такую таблицу

```
id  date        date_over   time        user_id    client_id
2   2017-11-22  2017-11-23  16:10:00    1          2    
3   2017-11-24  2017-11-25  12:10:00    1          1
```

то есть получить самое последнее date_over для каждого клиента

Comment: ну `group by client_id` вам конечно поможет, только с остальными колонками определитесь какие именно значения вы для них хотите получить, минимум/максимум или еще что нибудь по хитрее

Comment: @Mike Максимум хочу а group by у меня первые вхождения показывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все разобрался спасибо @Mike за подсказку

```
SELECT 
  client_id, MAX(date_over)
FROM
  crm.calls
WHERE
  user_id = 1
GROUP BY client_id;
```